# getChildHtml on category view

Tags: php, magento

I'm attempting to put a custom file containing featured items below the main product list on category pages on a Magento store.

I have edited catalog.xml to include:

```
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        ...
        </block>
        <block type="catalog/product" name="featuredcat" as="featuredcat" template="customphp/featured-cat.phtml"/>
    </block>
```

featuredcat.phtml includes a loop looking for products with a custom attribute (featured) selected. This works lovely, and is already in the sidebar.

I then add:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('featuredcat')
```

To the bottom of my catalog/category/view.phtml file. But nothing rendering. I could have sworn this would be correct. Can anyone shed light as to what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: Just a guess (hence the comment rather than an answer!) - That block type, 'catalog/product'....try changing that to 'catalog/product_list' as per the other pre-existing block.

Comment: Oops! No, that's my bad on abbreviating badly. It is after the closing block tag, and within the view.phtml block. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout xml you have provided has the `featuredcat` block appended directly to the `product_list` block.  So, you would have to call `getChildHtml` from within `catalog/product/list.phtml` and not `catalog/category/view.phtml`.

So, you can either move your `getChildHtml` call to the correct template as described above or move `featuredcat` block up a level:

```
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product" name="featuredcat" as="featuredcat" template="customphp/featured-cat.phtml"/>
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    ...
    </block>
</block>
```

Or you could keep your layout xml as is and use getChildChildHtml :) - but I'm sure changing your layout is the better option -

```
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('product_list', 'featuredcat') ?>
```

Comment: Oops, as explained above, no, that's just my bad on abbreviating badly. It is after the closing block tag, and within the view.phtml block. Apologies.

Comment: The layout xml you posted will work perfectly when nested correctly.  It could be as McNab pointed out that you are using a template dependant on the block type being catalog/product_list - have you checked your logs to see if there are any errors showing?

Comment: Hey Drew, thanks for your help. I can't believe this, but it's because of cache being on. I am a moron- this kind of thing only happens when I work on a Sunday!

Comment: Ha - no problem. Cache catches everyone out from time to time :)